# Decreasing the impact on a PDF's file size using iTextSharp to highlight text

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, filesize

I was able to successfully use the following code to highlight text in an existing PDF:

```
    private static void highlightDiff(PdfStamper stamper, Rectangle rectangle, int page)
    {
        float[] quadPoints = { rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Right, rectangle.Bottom, rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top, retangle.Right, rectangle.Top };
        PdfAnnotation highlight = PdfAnnotation.CreateMarkup(stamper.Writer, rectangle, null, PdfAnnotation.MARKUP_HIGHLIGHT, quadPoints);
        highlight.Color = BaseColor.RED;
        stamper.AddAnnotation(highlight, page);
    }
```

The problem is I'm highlighting characters at a time and my guess is a new layer is added every time I call this function because the resulting file size is significantly larger after the program has completed running.

I tried to add the following lines at the end of the function and maybe it's just me but it seemed to have sped up the time it takes the PDF to load when I go to view it but the size of the file still remains exceedingly large.

```
    stamper.FreeTextFlattening = true;
```

I may try to make my code more efficient and decrease the number of calls I make (if the characters I'm highlighting are next to each other, find the combined rectangle and call) but was wondering if there was another way around this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding a single Highlight annotation per page. The `QuadPoints` is a flat array of `8 x n` numbers. These numbers are 'stored as text', consider reducing their precision, anything beyond one digit (or even none at all) in fractional part is not necessary. Set `Rectangle` to page dimensions.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like an interesting approach. One annotation per page. Is it possible to collect all the rectangles I need to be highlighted and make a single call that does this all at once through one annotation?

Comment: 8 numbers for every 'character' (rectangular area to be highlighted) to the `quadPoints` array; the 2nd parameter for single (per page) call of `CreateMarkup` can be page boundaries, it should work.

Comment: So I was able to get it working with just one call like you suggested which made a decent amount of difference to the file size. Glad to know it can be done this way, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Each time you execute `highlightDiff` you add a new highlight annotation to the PDF. Inside the PDF such an annotation is an object like this:

```
1 0 obj
<<
    /Rect[204.68 705.11 211.2 716.11]
    /Subtype/Highlight
    /Contents()
    /QuadPoints[204.68 716.11 211.2 716.11 204.68 705.11 211.2 705.11]
    /C[1 0 0]
    /P 2 0 R
>>
```

Furthermore there needs to be a reference to this object from the page description plus an entry in the internal cross references.

Thus, each such call makes the PDF grow by nearly 200 bytes. If you highlight many such individual characters, the file indeed will grow considerably.

> I may try to make my code more efficient and decrease the number of calls I make (if the characters I'm highlighting are next to each other, find the combined rectangle and call) but was wondering if there was another way around this.

If you indeed want your highlighting to be done using highlighting annotations, there is not way around this.

If you on the other hand would also accept highlighting rectangles to be drawn in the regular page content, you may see less file size growth using that approach. Even then, though, first combining neighboring rectangles would reduce file size (and PDF viewer resource requirements) considerably.

Comment: Thanks for the background information! I'm new to working with PDFs but everything's slowly starting to make sense. I cut down on the number of calls and the file size has indeed shrunk. The end goal is to have specific characters in the text highlighted. If this can be done without annotations and as a result, without a major impact on the file size, I'm all for it.

Comment: Even without annotations there might be considerable file growth (albeit not as large as with annotations). The major objective should, therefore, be to combine the individual character highlights to larger ones.